# Creating a preferencs dialog for swing application

Tags: java, swing, model-view-controller, preferences

After years of working with shallow `.properties` files to hold preferences and settings of our application, we plan to create an MVC component for preferences dialog, backed up by some kind of model in file system or data base.

We aim to have something like eclipse (and many other IDE's and applications) has: a tree of application components on the left hand side of the dialog, each node in the list can have a matching preferences page with titles, sections, tabs and button groups.

We plan to make the GUI modular, and build according to xml files that define the GUI, and the relations between Swing controls to the matching properties.

So, before we begin inventing the wheel, I thought we could reuse some library that does exactly this.

I started investigating the eclipse source, but it's all SWT based, which I'm not sure how easy it is to integrate into our Swing based application.

So, does enyone know of a good java library to do the work for us?

Answer (score 2):

One candidate is [JIDE Dialogs](http://www.jidesoft.com/products/dialogs.htm). A variety of styles are supported.

You can start a demo from a browser [here](http://www.jidesoft.com/products/download.htm). In the tree on the left, select *Jide Dialogs>Options Dialog Demo*. Click one of the buttons that appear, to select a style.

In addition to providing the generic presentation layer for preferences, Eclipse's preferences framework also supports an optional persistence model, and a way to contribute preferences pages.